# How to delete values of one table based on multiple values from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
Table 1 = products (id, name, organisationId, subcategoryId)
Table 2 = products_attribute_attributes (productId, attributeId)
```

I am trying to delete from Table 2 where attributes match a specific attributeId AND relate to products from a number of different organisationIds.

What I have tried is below:

```
DELETE product_attributes_attribute FROM product_attributes_attribute
INNER JOIN product
ON  product.id = product_attributes_attribute.productId
WHERE attributeId = "154" AND organisationId IN (685,720,773,789,774,834,911,698);
```

MySQL gave me this response:

> Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.

As I don't know MySQL very well I am fairly sure that safe update mode is essential for me to keep enabled to prevent potentially disastrous mistakes so I don't intend to disable it. What I don't understand is why it thinks I haven't used a WHERE clause when you can see that it is there in the code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the primary key in `products_attribute_attributes`?

Answer (score 1):

seems you have not primary key  on your tables  so mysql  raise the error

```
DELETE product_attributes_attribute 
FROM product_attributes_attribute
INNER JOIN product ON  product.id = product_attributes_attribute.productId
WHERE attributeId = "154" 
AND organisationId IN (685,720,773,789,774,834,911,698);
```

you should OR alter you table and ad primary key for

```
table product
id 

table products_attribute_attributes
productId, attributeId
```

OR disable SQL_SAFE_UPDATES

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
```

Comment: But don't do option 2

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using mysql workbench. 
The error is because you are modifying data without a key column in the where condition in safe mode. 
You can disable Safe mode from workbench itself.

Edit-->preference-->SQL editor-->bottom of the page you have checkbox for safe mode(Screenshot attached)

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hm5BF.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I turned off safe mode and the below code worked:

DELETE product_attributes_attribute.* FROM product_attributes_attribute
INNER JOIN product
ON  product.id = product_attributes_attribute.productId
WHERE product_attributes_attribute.attributeId = "188" AND organisationId IN (685,720,773,789,774,834,911,698);